# ¿Por que este metodo no me funciona? JAVA

Tags: java, poo

Buenas hice un metodo de eliminar un cliente pero no funciona devuelve false , por que sera , antes daba true pero ahora no .

Esto es lo que hice (en una clase sistema):

```
public Boolean eliminarUsuario(Integer id) throws UsuarioIncorrectoException {

    Boolean eliminado = false;


    Iterator<Cliente> it = listaUsuarios.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {

        Cliente u = it.next();
        if (u.getId().equals(id)) {
            it.remove();
            eliminado = true;


        }else {
            eliminado=false;
            throw new UsuarioIncorrectoException();
        }

    }


    return eliminado;

}
```

y asi es como esta la clase Cliente :

```
public class Cliente extends Usuario implements Comparable <Cliente>{

private Integer puntos;
private Integer id;

public Cliente(String nombre, String apellido, String email, String password) {
    super(nombre, apellido, email, password);

    this.puntos = 0;
    this.id=(int)(Math.random()*200)+1;

}
public Cliente () {

}
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}



public Integer getPuntos() {
    return puntos;
}

public void setPuntos(Integer puntos) {
    this.puntos = puntos;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((puntos == null) ? 0 : puntos.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Cliente other = (Cliente) obj;
    if (puntos == null) {
        if (other.puntos != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!puntos.equals(other.puntos))
        return false;
    return true;
}


@Override
public int compareTo(Cliente c1) {

    return this.getNombre().compareTo(c1.getNombre());
}

}
```

y la clase Usuario que la hereda Cliente :

```
public abstract class Usuario {

    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String email;
    private String password;


    public Usuario(String nombre, String apellido, String email, String password) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellido = apellido;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;


    }

    public Usuario() {

    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}

Sistema s1 = new Sistema("Nuevo Sistema"); //por parametro recibe el nombre del sistema
Usuario u1 = new Cliente ("Lautaro", "Rodriguez", "laurz@gmail.com", "0321");
System.out.println(s1.eliminarUsuario(((Cliente) u1).getId()));//da false
```

Comment: Si ahora devuelve `false` es porque se esta cumpliendo la condición del `false`. ¿Estás revisando los datos con los que trabaja el código?

Answer (score 0):

Tu método no elimina el elemento deseado y esta retornando `true` simplemente porque no se esta cumpliendo la condición que indica que al iterar sobre la lista de usuarios no se tiene un elemento con el id que mandas llamar el método.

```
...
...
while (it.hasNext()) {

   if (u.getId().equals(id)) {
       it.remove();
       eliminado = true;
   }
 ...
 }
...
...
```

Para que elimine un elemento debes asegurar que en la lista se encuentre un elemento con el id que proporcionas al llamar el método. Si antes retornaba `true` se debe a que ahora probablemente cambiaron los ids.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que le veo a ese código es que si `listaUsuarios` tiene mas de 1 usuario y el usuario que estas buscando no esta al principio de la lista, el método se va a interrumpir por la excepción que estas levantando en el `else`.
Por ejemplo si en `listaUsuarios` tenes el u1, u2, u3 insertados en ese orden y estas buscando u3. Al preguntar `if (u.getId().equals(id))` eso te dará FALSE y ejecutara el código del `else` que esta levantando la excepción `throw new UsuarioIncorrectoException();` y se interrumpirá el método.